# Is the code in "The C++ Programming Language Third Edition" on page 854 correct?

Tags: c++

I try to learn C++. In "The C++ Programming  Language Third Edition" book I found code on page 854 (Appendix C.13.1):

```
template<class T> class X {
    static T def_val;
    static T* new_X(T a = def_val);
};

template<class T> T X<T>::def_val(0, 0);
template<class T> T* X<T>::new_X(T a) { /* ... */ }

template<> int X<int>::def_val<int> = 0;
template<> int* X<int>::new_X<int>(int i) { /* ... */ }
```

I modify it:

```
template<class T> class X {
    static T def_val;
    static T* new_X(T a = def_val);
};

template<class T> T X<T>::def_val(0, 0);
template<class T> T* X<T>::new_X(T a) { return new T(a); }

template<> int X<int>::def_val<int> = 0;
template<> int* X<int>::new_X<int>(int i) { return new int(i); }
```

But my compiler won't compile it:

```
1>main.cpp(15): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>main.cpp(15): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>main.cpp(15): error C2059: syntax error : '<'
1>main.cpp(16): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>main.cpp(16): error C2470: 'X<T>::new_X' : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>main.cpp(16): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>main.cpp(16): error C2059: syntax error : '<'
1>main.cpp(19): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>main.cpp(19): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

What wrong code in the book or compiler?

Comment: can you please show your main.cpp?

Comment: Your errror messages give line numbers, would be helpfull if you give the line numbers in your code (or at least write something like "x lines missing" in the first line of your code. And where comes the error, in the orginial code, or your modified?

Comment: Line 15 is "template<> int X<int>::def_val<int> = 0;"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't forget to mail Stroustrup. From his [homepage](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/3rd_errata.html):

> "As a small token of my gratitude to
>   people who report problems and thereby
>   help me improve the book, I offer a
>   reward to someone who first reports a
>   misspelling, a bug in a code example,
>   or a factual error in the text to me.
>   The bounty for new errors in the text
>   is US$32."

Edit: Oops. You are too late. The bug was fixed in the 19th printing. See [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/3rd_printing19.html). So no bounty, sorry!

The corrected version looks like this:

```
template class X {
    // ...
    static T def_val;
    static T* new_X(T a = def_val);
};

template< class T> T X<T>::def_val; // initialize to X<T>()
template< class T> T* X<T>::new_X(T a) { /* ... */ }

template< > int X<int>::def_val = 0;
template< > int* X<int>::new_X(int i) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 17):

The code from the book is wrong.  The last two lines should read:

```
template<> int X<int>::def_val = 0;
template<> int* X<int>::new_X(int i) { return new int(i); }
```

Answer (score 4):

You want

```
template<class T> class X {
    static T def_val;
    static T* new_X(T a = def_val);
};

template<class T> T X<T>::def_val(0, 0);
template<class T> T* X<T>::new_X(T a) { return new T(a); }

template<> int X<int>::def_val = 0;
template<> int* X<int>::new_X(int i) { return new int(i); }
```